# java SE. How to send post request with binary file?

Tags: java, post, upload, binary, request

I am working on a java app, to upload images on yfrog.com.
I can post on the API page successfully **but without binary files just with a string parameters**.
Also the method I use *only accept "String"*.

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```

`wr.write(data);` accept String only.

I tried to put the image path but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and take a look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).